# Change the value of a variable outside of a jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have this code where I want to iterate over some input fields with a certain data attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="asdf4faef4are" checked data-something="1" onchange="check()">
<input type="checkbox" name="fgrea4g3agere" checked data-something="2" onchange="check()">
```

and

```
function check(){
  var dont
  $('input[data-something]').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')=="true"){
        dont=true
    }
  });
  alert(dont)
}
```

but the variable `dont` is not filled because it is not set inside the function.

How do I transfer a variable to the outer global scope?

I want to check if all input fields are unchecked by the user.

---

Update: I found out! my example worked already just fine if I change `attr('checked')=="true"` to `attr('checked')==true` without quotes. But your Answer is a more elegant solution anyway. thanks ;)

Comment: I clarified my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check if all input fields are unchecked by the user.

In this case you can avoid the loop by using the `:checked` selector, and verifying that the `length` property is `0`. Try this:

```js
$('input[data-something]').change(function() {
  var noneChecked = $('input[data-something]:checked').length == 0;
  
  if (noneChecked)
    console.log('No items checked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="asdf4faef4are" checked="true" data-something="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="fgrea4g3agere" checked="true" data-something="2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code. You first need to initialise the variable and secondly, call it when the checkboxes are clicked/changed.

Just saw below statement and made changes to code accordingly.

> I want to check if all input fields are unchecked by the user.

```js
function checkAndAlert() {
  if ($('.someclass:checked').length == $('.someclass').length) {
    console.log("All are checked.");
  } else if ($('.someclass:checked').length == 0) {
    console.log("None are checked.");
  }
}

$(".someclass").on('change', function() {
  checkAndAlert();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="someclass" name="asdf4faef4are" data-something="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="someclass" name="fgrea4g3agere" data-something="2">
```

Comment: your first version was nearer to my attempt, can you roll back please and explain why yours is working and mine not?

Comment: Well, I thought your requirement is to check whether all are checked or not. If yes, this and above solution are perfect for it.

Comment: I found out! my example worked already just fine if I change `"true"` to `true`

Comment: Yes! that was mistake in your question. I removed.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you in your way..!

```js
$('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true)
function check(){
  var dont
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
     $(this).prop('checked', false)
        dont = true;
    } else {
     $(this).prop('checked', true)
     dont = false;
    }
  alert(dont)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="asdf4faef4are" data-something="1" onchange="check()">
<input type="checkbox" name="fgrea4g3agere" data-something="2" onchange="check()">
```